# Code duplication vs wordiness

Tags: php, array, comparative-review, constants

In [my program](https://github.com/Kolyunya/codeception-markup-validator/blob/master/sources/Lib/MarkupValidator/DefaultMessageFilter.php) I read values from a configuration array.

First I just used magic constants like this:

```
private $config = array(
    'ignoreWarnings' => true,
);

private function ignoreWarnings()
{
    if (is_bool($this->config['ignoreWarnings']) === false) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid "%s" config value.', 'ignoreWarnings'));
    }

    /* @var $ignoreWarnings bool */
    $ignoreWarnings = $this->config['ignoreWarnings'];

    return $ignoreWarnings;   
}
```

But then I moved the config key name to a class constant

```
private $config = array(
    self::IGNORE_WARNINGS_CONFIG_KEY => true,
);

private function ignoreWarnings()
{
    if (is_bool($this->config[self::IGNORE_WARNINGS_CONFIG_KEY]) === false) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid "%s" config value.', self::IGNORE_WARNINGS_CONFIG_KEY));
    }

    /* @var $ignoreWarnings bool */
    $ignoreWarnings = $this->config[self::IGNORE_WARNINGS_CONFIG_KEY];

    return $ignoreWarnings;
}
```

Pros:

- No code duplication
- No magic constants
- Impossible to make a typo
- Less error-prone
- Easier to make changes

Cons:

- ?

Which of the options would you stick to and why?

P.S. Custom config is injected via constructor like this

```
public function __construct(array $config = array())
{
    $this->config = array_merge($this->config, $config);
}
```

Comment: i think the first one if condition is good , because the second code , have a constant value ,this could make longer to read from the memory good luck bro

Comment: Ease of reading should be always preferred to ease of writing.

Comment: @YourCommonSense the question is which one is easier to read. That is very subjective. Whilst described pros are objective.

Comment: come on, stop writing the code right in the question body. you are supposed to have a ready made working code to ask here

Comment: Anyway, you forgot to test whether $this->config is set and whether self::IGNORE_WARNINGS_CONFIG_KEY is defined, which makes your code practically unusable

Comment: @YourCommonSense the config can not be unset.

Comment: @YourCommonSense what do you mean by `ready made`? It's in `master`.

Comment: Don't be silly. I mean the whole War and Peace novel in the [question history](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/161636/revisions).

Comment: What first code? What second code? What constant value?

Comment: sorry i  mean you write the function tow time ,  you post same function tow time but  the behavior change

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any improvement in your second option. To make this code indeed less duplicated i would create a dedicated method to get a configuration parameter and also would store the key in a variable:

```
protected function getBoolConfigParameter($key, $default = true)
{
    if (isset($this->config[$key]) && is_bool($this->config[$key])) {
        return $this->config[$key];
    }
    return $default;
}
protected function ignoreWarnings()
{
    return $this->getBoolConfigParameter(self::IGNORE_WARNINGS_CONFIG_KEY);
}
```

Comment: This is not going to work. Configuration parameter may be not `bool` but `string` or `array` instead.

Comment: Here you go. Bool parameters included.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The key name is still used in two places: in the default config and while retrieving value from the config.

Comment: My answer is perfectly within the scope of this site. If it doesn't answer your question then your question is off topic.